# Admob user consent with Android Compose (GDPR)

Tags: admob, android-jetpack-compose, ump

Admob has updated their bannerAds [sample codes](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-examples/tree/main/kotlin/admob/BannerExample/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/example/bannerexample) to include the user consent form (GoogleMobileAdsConsentManager.kt) .
Their codes uses xml for the layout and menu.

Was wondering if anyone have the Compose equivalent that integrates the GDPR consent form together with the Admob banner display?

my current codes just wraps the admob banner into a composable, without asking for consent.

```
@Composable
fun AdBanner(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    adMob: ApplicationAdViewAdMob3,
    adaptiveAdUnitId: Int = 0
) {

    AndroidView(
        factory = { context ->
            FrameLayout(context).apply {

                layoutParams =
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
                    )
            }
        },
        update = {
            adMob.loadAdaptiveAd(it, adaptiveAdUnitId)
        }, modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .wrapContentHeight()
    )

}
```